# Is It a Security Vulnerability To Allow Users To Dictate An MongoDB Object UUID? (NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, uuid

For our application, we use MongoDB, but we replace the ID as a UUID. The front-end application generates the UUID and sends that back to our NodeJS backend. The backend then checks that it's a valid UUID and uses that as the MongoDB object Id.

My question is, is it safe (security wise) to allow a front-end application/user to specify this UUID to be used as the Id of a MongoDB object?

My thoughts are:
1. If the user specifies a duplicate Id, the MongoDB driver won't insert the object (only happens if the user manually POSTs to the NodeJS API)
2. If the user specifies an invalid Id, the request is thrown out.

Is there anything else I'm missing?

Thanks! Also let me know if any part of the question isn't clear.

Comment: Guarding against potential (ab)use of your UUIDs is probably a better question for [Information Security StackExchange](https://security.stackexchange.com). I would describe any concerns you have specific to how you are using the UUIDs. Aside from [common security concerns](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data#Common_security_concerns) for form data, you generally need to ensure that any user-provided input is properly validated & sanitised for any context where it might be reused.

Comment: It sounds like you want to prevent users from creating invalid UUIDs but might be OK with custom UUIDs that meet a prescribed format and are still unique. Some other considerations that may apply to your use case: Do your UUIDs have any embedded data aspects (for example, a timestamp) that an adversary could potentially manipulate? Could a malicious user guess how to generate a sequence of upcoming UUIDs (and perhaps cause a delay or DOS for other users trying to insert new IDs already taken)? If a user manipulates the UUID could they potentially read or write data associated with other users?